# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project someProject: Could not exec java

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is from my pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xx.htns</groupId>
    <artifactId>someproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>someproject</name>
    <description>someproject</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
        <poi.version>3.9</poi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
      <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.8112</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.allegro.finance</groupId>
            <artifactId>tradukisto</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpg-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>castor</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.brownsocks</groupId>
            <artifactId>payments</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cheyanru.payments</groupId>
            <artifactId>enets</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.60</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is what my pom.xml looks like.

error message

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.171 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-09T12:33:25+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project testing : Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

In my command line I type "*java -version*" and below is the result

java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

from that result, I know that i

I was wondering if someone can point us if I'm doing something wrong here, or do we have an issue with 1.4.2.RELEASE?

Comment: remove the version from starter parent. try again.

Comment: cannot, once i comment out the version, an error "parent.version is missing"

Comment: Share your project through github. Need to check what have you have ?

Comment: i cant share becos the project contain some sensitive information

Comment: share the full pom at least.

Comment: Try using "mvn clean install -DskipTest" I suppose testcase create some issue.

Comment: @AnishB. I have updated my post with my entire pom

Comment: @DhwanilPatel I did a Project > clean still got same issue :(

Comment: Using same command as I mentioned in above? I also going to check your pom and update you asap.

Comment: run > run configuration > Goals > clean install -DskipTest

I ran this, same error message

Comment: Let me see what is the issue.

Comment: Posted the answer. Have a look on that.

Comment: Could try- <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source> <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target> can you add this under <properties> in pom.xml and do a maven clean install. Also try to resolve this issue, if you missed then just add class which denotes with @SpringBootApplication annotation. Our main method delegates to Spring Boot's SpringApplication class by calling run method.

Comment: tried, cant work :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new work space. Thats all...omg took me whole day :(
I have no absolute idea how and why..